# I used fastlane to upload to Beta, i put promote_to_track

Tags: fastlane, promoted-builds

I used fastlane to upload to Beta, i put promote_to_track : production filed, is this flag will uploaded to production directly without testing.
If this is the case it will upload to beta and production directly why this is promoted. 
Please help me to understand this point if i put promote to production it will be uploaded to production dictrly without review or testing, please advice

Comment: What exactly is your question? What fastlane actions are you using? If your question is about `supply`/`upload_to_play_store`, here is the documentation for the "promote" stuff: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#track-promotion

Comment: My question what is the field promote_to_track is doing  if i put in in upload_to_play_store these fileds track: beta, and promote_to_track :production, it will uploaded on beta and production so this will live or on production is need action to go live @janpio

Comment: `track_promote_to` is the target of where you want to promote the app from `track` to. You usually don't upload and promote at the same time, but upload to e.g. "beta" and then promote from beta to "production". That would mean parameters `--track_promote_to production --track beta` for example.

Comment: So if i put --track_promote_to production --track beta, it will upload to beta and production in same time? @janpio

Comment: Probably not. As I wrote, promoting and uploading are probably not meant to be done at the same time. You first upload to a specific track, then later promote to another track when testing was successful. It doesn't really make sense to upload the same file to two tracks at the same time, does it?